# Linux kernel error: patch refuses to compile

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linux-kernel

here is the code that i wrote: [link](https://github.com/sirmordred/ref-3.10/commit/3674fd24cfc87fb9cc5dba51780e6a4dc04c0e4b)

and im selecting the following defconfig(exynos8890-herolte_kor_defconfig) for compiling [defconfig file](https://github.com/sirmordred/ref-3.10/blob/universal8890/arch/arm64/configs/exynos8890-herolte_kor_defconfig)

and my core function (`kernel/examplepatch/core.c`) is depend on the following options as described in `kernel/example/Kconfig`

```
config HAVE_EXAMPLEPATCH
    bool
    help
      Arch supports kernel example patch

config EXAMPLEPATCH
    bool "Kernel example patch"
    depends on DYNAMIC_FTRACE2
    depends on MODULES
    depends on SYSFS
    depends on KALLSYMS_ALL
    depends on HAVE_EXAMPLEPATCH
    help
      Say Y here if you want to support kernel example patch.
```

and the following options `depends on MODULES` , `depends on SYSFS` and `depends on KALLSYMS_ALL` are selected through defconfig which i selected at compile time(exynos8890-herolte_kor_defconfig) and the rest dependencies `depends on HAVE_EXAMPLEPATCH` and `depends on DYNAMIC_FTRACE2` are selected through arch/arm64/Kconfig [link](https://github.com/sirmordred/ref-3.10/commit/3674fd24cfc87fb9cc5dba51780e6a4dc04c0e4b#diff-74b704a6995edb0529fc619230b82b94R79) within CONFIG_ARM64(and exynos8890-herolte_kor_defconfig has CONFIG_ARM64 option too)

but unfortunatly the `kernel/examplepatch/core.c` refuses to compile i cant see the **core.o** (compiled object) in `kernel/examplepatch`

so what part or things are wrong?

thanx
regards

Comment: *"refuses to compile"* ?? What does that mean? Do you have a Makefile? Update: OK, I see you do...

Comment: i mean i cant see any **core.o** (compiled object) in `kernel/examplepatch` after compilation. and yes i have makefile here https://github.com/sirmordred/ref-3.10/blob/3674fd24cfc87fb9cc5dba51780e6a4dc04c0e4b/kernel/examplepatch/Makefile

Comment: and also sorry for bad english :/

Comment: I think you need to add the `core.o` to your `obj-$(CONFIG_EXAMPLEPATCH)`

Comment: firstly i choosed the following implementation https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/livepatch/Makefile as a base thats why i added **examplepatch-objs** to core.o but i will try and inform you thank you so much